# How to create a Material Design Color Pallete in Delphi

Tags: delphi, material-design, tcolor

I hope to implement a material design color palette in delphi,[image]

but I don't know how to generate a palette that looks like the picture above.

How to generate a scale from 100 to 700 for a given color?

```
TMaterialColor = class
constructor Create(Color: TColor);
property _100: Tcolor read f_100;
property _200: Tcolor read f_200;
property _300: Tcolor read f_300;
property _400: Tcolor read f_400;
property _500: Tcolor read f_500;
property _600: Tcolor read f_100;
property _700: Tcolor read f_700;  {Shift + Ctrl  + C to generate code snippet}
end
implementation
constructor TMaterialColor.Create;
begin
f_100 := ? ;
f_200 := ? ;
f_300 := ? ;
f_400 := ? ;
f_500 := ? ;
f_600 := ? ;
f_700 := ? ;
end;
```

Comment: This is a rather broad question: it involves custom control creation, GDI drawing (or equivalent), and RGB/HSV conversion.

Comment: I don't believe, I just need the Hexadecimal code for each 100-700 gamma

Comment: You don't... Original Material colors are hand picked, there is no formula. You can find exact values here [Material Colors](https://material.io/design/color/#tools-for-picking-colors) You can also try finding some formula that will approximate colors, but it is hard to say how well it will work.

Comment: That chart appears to be using lightness as the variable. Try interpolating between the target color and white.

Comment: Interpolating between the target and white don't solves this question because I can't evaluate how afar the color is from white. If you know an algorithm to calculate the 700 level (100%, look picture) of any color, then share with me and we will get success to stepsize the pallet. thks